# How to use Pycharm built-in server to launch tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm

I recently read that Pycharm has a built-in web server. I don't know what that means exactly, but I'm wondering if it can be used to launch tensorboard instead of relying on chrome or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't, Google Chrome is a web browser, and you can't replace a web browser with a web server. Tensorboard has its own web server.